# Azure AD B2C iOS app token error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

This is the configuration of my app:

[image]

This is the sign in and sign up policy

[image]

Now this is the error it gives me when I run the following code with my configurations: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal

Error is given below:

```
Could not acquire token: Error Domain=MSALErrorDomain Code=-42105 "(null)" UserInfo={MSALErrorDescriptionKey=Token response is missing the access token}
```

[image]

Comment: i'm getting same error.Did you got the solution?

Comment: Any news regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please check
[sample on my GitHub.](https://github.com/Daniel-Krzyczkowski/Misc/tree/master/AzureB2Capp)

You have to add proper scope:

let kScopes: [String] = ["https://YOUR_TENANT/api/user_impersonation"]

Please let me know if you were able to solve the problem.

Comment: Sample is ok but it is crucial to set the right scopes in the Azure portal for the application in the AD B2C. In the "API access" there should be "Access the user's profile: and for it you should select these two scopes:
https://i.ibb.co/RCyDBKv/adb2ctoken.png

Comment: All right, but still not able to login. So, something is wrong.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? I will try to help.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, you were right. I was missing one more scope (except openid and offline_access) which is user_impersonation. Thank you very much